# Adding X-Frame-Options to heroku rails 2.3.15 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, x-frame-options

I've found many answers on how to remove X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN, but I've been unable to find a correct answer for how to add it.

The app is on Heroku and is running under Rails 2.3.15 (nginx).  I don't think it is a Sinatra app (I say this only because there is no config.ru. A friend built the app for me and he's unable to help out now, so I'm not positive.)

I tried adding the following to /app/controllers/application_controller.rb but it just made every page return a 503:

> config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
>       'X-Frame-Options' => 'SAMEORIGIN'   }

When that failed I tried this syntax instead, in the same file:

```
def set_x_frame_options
  response.headers["X-Frame-Options"] = "SAMEORIGIN"
end
```

That doesn't seem to break anything, but there are also no new http headers added.

As you may be able to tell, I barely know what I'm talking about here, so please feel free to talk to me like I'm a n00b in your answer. :-)

-=-=- edit -=-=-=-

Figured it out myself for adding http header for pages served from the app itself.

Added this to /app/controllers/application_controller.rb :

> before_filter :default_headers
>
> ```
> def default_headers
>   headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'SAMEORIGIN'
> end
> ```

Still not sure how to add it to a few pages I have outsite the app, in /public/, so pointers welcome on that front.

Comment: Hi @StefanLasiewski ,   I tried but was told via error message that I had to wait >= 8 hours before doing so. The error mesage included a suggestion to add the answer to the initial post by means of an an edit instead, so I did. :-)

Comment: Oh, but that leaves it languishing in the 'unanswered' filter.  Fixing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out myself for adding http header for pages served from the app itself.

Added this to /app/controllers/application_controller.rb :

> before_filter :default_headers
>
> ```
> def default_headers
>   headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'SAMEORIGIN'
> end
> ```

Still not sure how to add it to a few pages I have outsite the app, in /public/, so pointers welcome on that front.